# How to concat two 3D row-major arrays in C++ along the 1st dimension?

Tags: c++

Currently I don't know of a simple way to do this other than to simply:

1. Allocate new memory for the combined arrays
2. Go index by index and copy each item from each array into the new array, keeping in mind that it should be row-major order

Wondering if there is a faster/more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: Are they stored as arrays of arrays?

Comment: I believe they can be, given arrays seem to be row-major by default in C++ (https://www.mathworks.com/help/coder/ug/what-are-column-major-and-row-major-representation-1.html).